# Matlab adding rows and columns elegantly

Tags: matlab, image-processing, matrix, vectorization, linear-algebra

Say that we have the following random matrix:

```
1 2 3 4
5 6 7 8
9 8 7 6
5 4 3 2
```

I'd like to transform it into the following:

```
1 0 2 0 3 0 4 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
5 0 6 0 7 0 8 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
9 0 8 0 7 0 6 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
5 0 4 0 3 0 2 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

For some reason I cannot use mathjax format so it looks a bit awful, sorry for this. Point, is, that I want to add row and columns of zeros in between of my current rows and columns so that I increase its size 2x.

I came up with the following code, but it only works for very small matrixes if i use it on a a big image it cannot finish due to memory limitation problems.

```
clear all

I=imread('image.png');
I=rgb2gray(I);

B=zeros(2*size(I));

[x, y]=find(-inf<I<inf);

xy=[x,y];
nxy=xy;

%coord change
nxy=2*xy-1;

B(nxy(:,1),nxy(:,2))=I(xy(:,1),xy(:,2));
```

I expected to be fast because it is fully vectorised with maltlab functions but it fails miserably. Is there some other elegant way to do this?

Comment: For your information, mathjax doesn't work simply because Stack Overflow doesn't support it:) It's sometimes missed, but a lot of questions that would make heavy use of it are off-topic anyway. (Yours is not.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you take a look at your indexing vectors, this is something like `I([1 1 2 2] ,[1 2 1 2]  );` for a 2x2 matrix which means you index each row and column twice. The right solution is `B(1:2:end,1:2:end)=I;` which indexes every second row and every second column.

Comment: That was it. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

This can be also done via the one liner, say your original matrix is called `A`, then

```
kron(A,[1,0;0,0])
```

Comment: This should be the preferred the solution, at least for 2d arrays. `kron` does exactly what's required, and is much more generalizable.